# Grub Installation in kali Linux

Tags: linux, installation, grub

Kali linux installation time this message show "the grub-pc package failed to install into /target/ withuot the GRUB boot loader the install system will not boot". 
My PC configuration:

### System Information

Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
System Manufacturer: MSI
System Model: MS-7817
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4160 CPU @ 3.60GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.6GHz
Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3974MB RAM
Page File: 1917MB used, 6028MB available[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTp2r.png)
DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 64bit Unicode

Answer (score 0):

Need more information...

It sounds like you are trying to install kali linux with grub as your bootloader and that step is failing. Is this from within kali linux on a bootable drive?

Comment: Yes. i used bootable pendrive.

Comment: My first problem is cd-rom then this message show "the grub-pc package failed to install into /target/ withuot the GRUB boot loader the install system will not boot".